# Como somar a cada valor de uma lista, um número que depende de outro aleatório?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista com 21 termos e um valor que vai de 0 até um número aleatório que varia de zero até o número digitado pelo usuário. Eu preciso dividir esse número aleatório em números menores que somem o aleatório, por exemplo:

O número aleatório gerado foi 100, eu posso dividir nos números 50, 25, 10, 15 (e mais 17 zeros) e depois somar cada pedaço disso em um termo que eu escolher da lista (não pode ser aleatório e nem em ordem, tem que ser arbitrário)

O problema é que eu não sei como fazer isso, eu pensei em fazer um `for` que contenha um número aleatório q varia de 0 até o número digitado, mas nem montar isso eu sei, alguma ideia?

(O esquema seria na forma:

```
x = randint (0,pat) #pat é a variável digitada pelo usuário
x2 = randint (0,pat - x)
x3 = randint (0,pat - x2)
```

Até (`pat` menos a variável dar zero), em que seria simplesmente repetido o número zero várias vezes)

Comment: Amigo, ainda está confuso o que você quer, esse é o código inteiro ?

Comment: O começo do código é composto por três listas, com diferentes tamanhos. O usuário deve digitar um número que vai ser dividido em 3 porcentagens aleatórias.
Isso significa que eu vou ter três números, cada um associado a uma das listas (Um desses números é a variável pat). Com a pat eu preciso dividir ela de novo, no número de vezes da lista associada a ela e somar a cada variável esse valor, que pode ser igual a zero. @FourZeroFive

Comment: Esta questão está muito confusa. Não estão claros quis são os `inputs` tampouco os `outputs`. Nesta questão não ficou claro, com quais listas devemos trabalhar, o tipo de variável da lista, e nem o range de tais listas. Não ficou claro quais percentagens seriam. Muito confusa esta pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer um ciclo e subtrair o valor inserido em cada iteração.

```
from random import randint

pat = int(input("Inserir número: ")) 

lista = []
valor_parcial = pat
for i in range(0,21):
    x = randint(0, valor_parcial)
    lista.append(x)
    valor_parcial -= x

print(lista)
```

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas pat iria acabar variando de forma que ficaria maior que antes, minha solução foi usar um while com 2 for e 3 ifs, mas obrigado pela ajuda